# C++ macro expression containing return (like Rust's try!)

Tags: c++, macros

Rust has a macro which is an expression that either evaluates to some value, or returns from the function. Is there any way to do this in C++?

Something like this:

```
struct Result
{
    bool ok;
    int value;
}

Result foo() { ... }

#define TRY(x) (auto& ref = (x), ref.ok ? ref.value : return -1)

int main()
{
    int i = TRY(foo());
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work because `return` is a statement not an expression. There are other problems with the above code but it roughly gives an idea of what I want. Does anyone have any bright ideas?

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/oktal/result

Comment: Just to make sure.. You have foo() that returns an instance of 'Result' and if 'ok == false' you would like to have a default value. Is that what you want ?

Comment: @AlexG: No I want to return an error from the function if `ok == false`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Ah awesome thanks! Looks like they had to resort to extensions: "Note that this macro uses a special extension called compound statement only supported by gcc and clang"

Comment: @Timmmm Yeah.  Most of the stuff I'm seeing looks like with the tools we currently have in C++ this is not something that can be done.  I'm not sure if I believe that but I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: You can do this cleanly and easily if you throw an exception on failure rather than returning an error code. Since that's anyway often better style, would it answer your question?

Comment: @Useless: I did consider it but throwing an exception is a totally different behaviour to returning an error code. Rust's error-handling style is much nicer than exceptions so I don't really want to use those.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to NathanOliver's [link](https://github.com/oktal/result) it looks like you can do it with [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) which are apparently only supported by Clang and GCC. Something like this:

```
#define TRY(x)                                                     \
    ({                                                             \
        auto& ref = (x);                                           \
        if (!ref.ok) {                                             \
            return -1;                                             \
        }                                                          \
        ref.value; // The block evaluates to the last expression.  \
    })
```

Comment: does this support `int i = TRY(foo());`?

Comment: Yes it does! :-)